# A Sequence is Square Summable if and only if....

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $\{z_k\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of complex numbers. Is it true that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{2k^2}{4k^2 + 8k +3} |z_k|^2 < \infty$ if and only if $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} |z_k|^2 < \infty$. I'm not really sure how to approach this problem? I was able to reduce a way more complicated problem to determining whether this is true, but I don't remember much about series.

EDIT:

I ran the sum through Wolframalpha for $z_k = \frac{1}{k}$ and $z_k = \frac{1}{2^k}$, and it converges in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: You can check that $$\dfrac{2}{15} \le \dfrac{2k^2}{4k^2+8k+3} \le \dfrac{1}{2}$$ for all integers $k \ge 1$. Try using this fact along with the comparison test.